# Fast conversion to multiindexed pandas dataframe using bincounts

Tags: python, loops, pandas, numpy

I have data from users who have left star ratings (1, 2 or 3 stars) on items in various categories, where each item may belong to multiple categories. In my current dataframe, each row represents a rating and the categories are one-hot encoded, like so:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_old = pd.DataFrame({
    'user': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'rate': [3, 2, 1, 1, 2],
    'cat1': [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    'cat2': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
})
#    user  rate  cat1  cat2
# 0     1     3     1     0
# 1     1     2     0     1
# 2     2     1     1     0
# 3     2     1     1     0
# 4     2     2     1     1
```

I want to convert this to a new dataframe, multiindexed by `user` and `rate`, which show the per-category bincounts for each star rating. I'm currently doing this with loops:

```
multi_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [df_old.user.unique(), range(1,4)],
    names=['user', 'rate']
)

df_new = pd.DataFrame(  # preallocate in an attempt to speed up the code
    {'cat1': np.nan, 'cat2': np.nan},
    index=multi_idx
)

df_new.sort_index(inplace=True)
idx = pd.IndexSlice

for uid in df_old.user.unique():
    for cat in ['cat1', 'cat2']:
        df_new.loc[idx[uid, :], cat] = np.bincount(
            df_old.loc[(df_old.user == uid) & (df_old[cat] == 1),
                       'rate'].values, minlength=4)[1:]
#            cat1  cat2
# user rate            
# 1    1      0.0   0.0
#      2      0.0   1.0
#      3      1.0   0.0
# 2    1      2.0   0.0
#      2      1.0   1.0
#      3      0.0   0.0
```

Unfortunately the above code is hopelessly slow on my real dataframe, which is long and contains many categories. How can I eliminate the loops please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your *multi-index*, you can aggregate your old data frame, and reindex it:

```
df_old.groupby(['user', 'rate']).sum().reindex(multi_idx).fillna(0)
```

[image]

---

Or as @piRSquared commented, do the reindex and fill missing value at one step:

```
df_old.groupby(['user', 'rate']).sum().reindex(multi_idx, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: use `fill_value` and preserve `dtype`  `df_old.groupby(['user', 'rate']).sum().reindex(multi_idx, fill_value=0)`  +1 from me ;-)

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks for the comment and +1.